# Element-wise concatenation of 2 vectors in kdb+

Tags: kdb

Given 2 vectors `A` and `B`, I want to concatenate each element of `A` with each element of `B`. For example if `A` and `B` were as follows:

```
A: 0 1 2 
B: 3 4 5
```

then the output should be `(0 3;1 4; 2 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also instantiate through the following

(A;B) to create a 2x3 matrix which can be flipped to get what you require

```
q)A:0 1 2
q)B:3 4 5
q)(A;B)
0 1 2
3 4 5
q)flip (A;B)
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Joining the two vectors using the [each](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each) (each-both in this case) iterator returns your desired output.

```
q)0N!A,'B
(0 3;1 4;2 5)
0 3
1 4
2 5
```